# Calling Sort in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

A lot of Similar Questions were answered, but not finding this one.  I am calling a Sort in Excel VBA.  The sort does work and sticks when the file is saved.  However, when the file is reopened, it errors.  After the repair, all seems well, and the sort is still in place:

> Dialog Box: "Repaires to 'ISOLATION DataEntry.xlsm"
> Dialog: Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content . . . 
> Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
> Error File: error0228880_01.xlm
> Error File Text:  
> error028880_01.xmlErrors were detected in file 'C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\CONVERSIONS\ISOLATION DataEntry.xlsm'Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

I can find nothing which would seem to cause the error.  I can deal without the sort, but would like to know what is causing it.  My project has 804 lines of VBA exclusive of the following Sort which is called:

```
Sub sortMaster()

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A1:I1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The code errors? Or the file errors? Or you have faulty data?

Comment: I copied the code.  When the Call runs, it seems fine.  The table sorts as required.  It is when I save/close the workbook and then reopen it that I get the error.

Comment: That doesn't strike me as an error with VBA, but a corrupted file (?).  I wonder if you're having additional "extra" SortFields being added since you don't first call `.SortFields.Clear`?

Comment: Am dong a rebuild and adding your clear suggestion would help clarify . . . is the file corrupted or is it a coding deficiency.